# Set php session via ajax

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to build my AJAX login system but I'm having some problems with PHP sessions.

This is the AJAX code I use in my `index.php`:

```
$("#buttonLogin").click(function(){
    $.post("<?php echo $AJAX ?>/ajaxLogin.php",{
        Username : $("#loginUsername").val(),
        Password : $("#loginPassword").val()
    }, 
    function(result){
        if(result == "OK"){
            window.location.href = "<?php echo $PUBLIC?>/home.php";
        } else {
            $("#loginMessageError").show();
        }
    });
});
```

And this is `ajaxLogin.php` that is called via AJAX:

```
<?php
require_once("../settings.php");
require_once($ABS_ENGINE."/classUser.php");

$user = new User();
if($user->loginUser($_POST["Username"], $_POST["Password"])){
    $UserID = $user->getUserId($_POST["Username"]);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

When I'm in `home.php` and I try to echo `$_SESSION["UserID"]`, I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: UserID in C:\xampp\htdocs\webname\resources\templates\headerHome.php on line 23

Probably this is not correct because session must be set before any output but if i try to echo `$_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;` line it's session variable is correctly displayed.

Comment: The only other explanation is that multiple session are being started. Check session_id() of both pages to verify this

Comment: Are you sure your php.ini is set to use session cookies and the path is an accessible one by PHP? There could be a chance that the session saving path is wrong for your setup.

Comment: @Paul Can you tell me how php.ini should be changed to allow sessions?

Comment: @MaterMorbi http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php There you go, set those up according to what you need, read the docs and you'll figure them out. Also read the comments in php.ini at the session section.

Comment: @MaterMorbi, have you checked the session_id() of the two pages..

Comment: @Starx PHPSESSID in chrome is correctly set.

Comment: @Starx - i had a similar problem. it IS the session_id(). one method im calling it, is as a rest api from a js app. how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

You need to initiate the session first, like session_start().then only you can have the access to session variables. Have a look at this simple example , it might help you:

**aj.php**

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'sess.php',
        data: {
            user : 'guna',

              },
        success : function(data){
                       alert(data);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {alert ("Error Occured");}
                 });


});
</script>
</html>
```

**sess.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']=$_GET['user'];
echo $_SESSION['user'];
?>
```

As other guys pointed out, better you can also check for session_start() in the page where you reading the session variables.

Answer (score 4):

When I had this kind of problem, the thing that solved it was using `exit();`

```
<?php
require_once("../settings.php");
require_once($ABS_ENGINE."/classUser.php");

$user = new User();
if($user->loginUser($_POST["Username"], $_POST["Password"])){
    $UserID = $user->getUserId($_POST["Username"]);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;
    echo "OK";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Comment: Yup, this worked for me too, loosely. If you're using Drupal with a non-core delivery callback, call `drupal_session_commit();` in your delivery callback.

Answer (score 0):

Better check if `session_start()` is present in home.php. Without this you will not be able to read the session data.

When you are doing `echo $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;` you will assigning and accessing at a same line, so it will obviously work.

Comment: `session_start()` is present in home.php