# .How is it possible to set php session in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have an ajax which log in but unable to set up a php session.

How is it possible to set session by php in ajax?

I already start the session in header but when this below script runs it always show me that session is true.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loc=true;
    var php_var;
    // process the form
    $('#loginform').submit(function(event) {

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData2 = {
            'email'              : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'password'           : $('input[name=password]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'http://example/api/v1/login', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData2, // our data object
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){        
            console.log(data);      
                if(data.error){
                    //show error message here
                    $('#name-group').html('<p>'+data.message);  
                <?php $_SESSION['isloggedIn']=false;?>
                }else{

                    //handle success part       
                    $('#name-group').html('<p>Login Successful');
                    <?php $_SESSION['isloggedIn']=true;?>

                }               
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                //request error 

                $('#name-group').html('<p>'+textStatus.message);
                console.log('jqXHR:');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('textStatus:');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log('errorThrown:');
                console.log(errorThrown);   
              }             
        });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694341/set-php-session-via-ajax .....................

Comment: just noticed is it correct: `$('#name-group').html('<p>'+data.message);`

Comment: @jai it return the data.response .... that was not an error

Comment: @MainakRay my point is `<p>+data.message`, don't you think there should be closing too.

Comment: Your seeing it all wrong. Ajax's purpose is to send data from the client side to the server side and vice versa. Think of it as a remote website that has nothing to do with your site, even if you have session start in there it would hold no purpose and would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing clientside with serverside code, the php code get executed before the user get the page in the browser, so as you did it with the api, use an ajax request to a php site on your server and set there the session. Don't forget the `session_start()`.