# Jquery ajax set some session variables then trigger click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a page that has tabs on it.  each of the tabs have a few forms on it.  On the form, a user can set a filter.  for example "Show me (10,25,100) result"

The when user enters a value, i fire off an ajax call to a php script that sets session variables

```
 $_SESSION['filter'] = $_POST['filter'];
```

The success of the ajax call triggers the tab click to get to the form the user is on:

```
 $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      data:"filter="+filter,
      url:"actions/Tickets/filters.php",
      success:function(result){
         $('#someTab').trigger('click');
      }
 });
```

The problem I am running into is if I

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

on the page that the form is on, i do not see any changes to the $_SESSION['filter'] value.

What i think is happening is the ajax isnt waiting for the script to finish, so the SESSION var never gets set.  asynch isnt an option.  how can i acheive this?

How can i use an ajax script to call a php file to set SESSION variables then trigger a click event on nav tabs.

Comment: Ofcourse you cant assign like that because js is client side script & php is server side, you can assign php variable to js variable but not vice versa

Comment: Try doing $_SESSION['filter'] = $_POST["filter"];

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated in the comment that you set the session using:

```
 $_SESSION['filter'] = $_POST['filter'];
```

Than, I think the issue is, when you set the session in php uisng an ajax call, than you can only get the updated session by using an another ajax call or after page refresh. So make an another ajax call and see what happens.

Comment: yea, i wrote that to shorten up the whole question. I apologize for the confusion.  The php script that sets the session vars is $_SESSION['filter'] = $_POST['filter'];

Answer (score 0):

You cann't assign session in javascript because javascript occurs on client side and session stored at server side.
So , It's not possible you can use php variables in js like.

```
<?php 
$_SESSION['filter'] = "foo";
?>
```

Then you can use this session variable in `js`. But you can't do vice versa. You can't assign session from `js` to `php`.

You can set value from `js` to `html` using jquery but this scenario isn't possible.

**Edit :-**

So, set session variable in `filter.php`.

```
$_SESSION['filter'] = "foo";
```

After then when result is retured reload the page. Because Page must be reload for session set. I'm not sure for it but may be it works.

```
 $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      data:"filter="+filter,
      url:"actions/Tickets/filters.php",
      success:function(result){
         $('#someTab').trigger('click');
         location.reload(); // reload the page
      }
 });
```

Comment: correct, the js calls the php script. php sets some variabiles. then js reloads the page via the trigger('click'). wouldn't that page reload now have the new session variables? I should add, the click event on the tab, is a seperate ajax call that calls the form page.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you cant assign like that because js is client side script & php is server side, you can assign php variable to js variable but not vice versa

**You need to use this:**

`$_SESSION['filter'] = $_POST["filter"];`

This post may help you:
[Set php session via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694341/set-php-session-via-ajax)

Comment: correct, the js calls the php script.  php sets some variabiles.  then js reloads the page via the trigger('click').  wouldn't that page reload now have the new session variables?  I should add, the click event on the tab, is a seperate ajax call that calls the form page.

Comment: @bart2puck plz follow the link in my edited answer that may help you.